# How to display the list of followers of a user in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask, I have a created a social media blog using Flask and I have used flask-SQLAlchemy database. I have incorporated the follow feature in blog, now I want to display the list of followers of a user and I have been getting an error and the results are not getting displayed.

Here is the code:
the route to display followers

```
@app.route("/userListFollowers/<username>")
@login_required
def listFollowers(username):    
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    folruser = user.followers.all()
    return render_template('userListFollowers.html', users=folruser)
```

the userListFollowers.html file that displays the list of followers

```
{%extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Followers</h2>
  {% for users in listFollowers%}
        <a href="{{url_for('user', username=username.username)}}">{{username.username}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I can't really understand how to get this working.

This is the error[image: Error]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is the error you get? And you are not passing `folruser` anywhere? Can you post the route for `listFollowers`?

Comment: Hi @Erich I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You should be using render_template to render HTML templates, you are returning a redirect to the same view function so you keep endlessly redirecting.

Also you need to pass your list of followers into the render_template function so that it will render them with your Jinja code

For your jinja code:

```
{%extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Followers</h2>
<ul>  
{% for users in listFollowers%}
        <li><a href="{{url_for('user', username=users.username)}}">{{users.username}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have done what you have mentioned, now the error page is not being displayed, but the page is blank there is nothing being displayed

Comment: Also the code snippets in the question have now been updated

Comment: So your Jinja code refers to listFollowers but you are not passing that in.  In your render_template function replace users=folruser with listFollowers=folruser.  Also in your Jinja loop in your url_for function you refer to an object username with a username attribute, but that does not seem to be made available to Jinja

Comment: referring to other templates I changed that too but it still doesn't display results

Comment: So I added to my answer the tweak I think you need to make to get your results to show up.

Comment: Thank You for the help, but that too doesn't display any results .....